# Eclipse IDE won't start

Tags: eclipse

With no specific reason suddenly when I start eclipse it shows the splash screen and then disappers and never starts. After doinng some reasearch and starting it with the command prompt with -clean it says: "An error occurred. See the log file...".

the .log file can be found : [here](https://justpaste.it/1imn2)

Thank you

Comment: When did the error appear first? Did you install any new plugins, or update Java? When you download a new Eclipse, does that run? If so, are there differences in the `eclipse.ini` file between the "fresh" and your version?

Comment: actually it appeared first after I uninstalled and deleted the ubuntu partition from my system (not sure if this is related to the issue though). I tried to reinstall eclipse but I get an error even during the install there.

Comment: How do you install Eclipse? I usually just download and unzip one of the archives, without installation. Does that work? Also, could you clear the log and start Eclipse again, then show the log with only the relevant information?

Comment: thanks for your replys. 
when trying to reinstall I was downloading eclipse oxygen 64bit installer from their website.
first, here is the log of the failed eclipse installation (eclipse oxygen from their site): https://justpaste.it/1inxn
I wasn't sure how to clear the eclipse log, so I just deleted any previously created log files in configuration folder and uploaded to newly created one (after eclipse failing to start): https://justpaste.it/1iny6

And now I downloaded the zip and eclipse run fine with it!
I think I'll stick with the zip and just run it from there.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Please check the config.ini file in the configuration folder under eclipse to make sure there is a valid value assigned for eclipse.application and eclipse.product.
You could use the below default values:
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide